# Merging Polygons in Shape Files with Common Tag IDs: unionSpatialPolygons

Tags: r, plot, rgdal, r-maptools

I am trying to read from a shape file and merge the polygons with a common tag ID.

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
if (!require(gpclib)) install.packages("gpclib", type="source")
gpclibPermit()

usa <- readOGR(dsn = "./path_to_data/", layer="the_name_of_shape_file")
usaIDs <- usa$segment_ID
isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus())
usaUnion <- unionSpatialPolygons(usa, usaIDs)
```

When I try to plot the merged polygons:

```
for(i in c(1:length(names(usaUnion)))){
  print(i)
  myPol <- usaUnion@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
  polygon(myPol, pch = 2, cex = 0.3, col = i)
}
```

[image]

all the merged segments looks fine except those in around Michigan for which the merger happens in a very weird way such that the resulted area for this particular segment, gives only a small polygon as below.

```
i = 10
usaUnion@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
```

output:

```
          [,1]     [,2] 
 [1,] -88.62533 48.03317
 [2,] -88.90155 47.96025
 [3,] -89.02862 47.85066
 [4,] -89.13988 47.82408
 [5,] -89.19292 47.84461
 [6,] -89.20179 47.88386
 [7,] -89.15610 47.93923
 [8,] -88.49753 48.17380
 [9,] -88.62533 48.03317
```

which turned out to be a small northern island:

[image]

I suspect the problem is that for some reason the `unionSpatialPolygons` function does not like geographically separated polygons [left and right side of Michigan], but I could not find a solution to it yet.

Here is the [link to input data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qC0Q51l102tdGsQ15EFSUE-CULmcOGJt) as you can reproduce.

Comment: Can you make this reproducible, by making a toy example with a few polygons that also does this, or by providing your shapefile somehow?

Comment: I got the shapefile and this should be reproducible now. I update the post with the link to the sample data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is not with `unionSpatialPolygons` but with your plot. Specifically, you are plotting only the first *'sub-polygon'* for each ID. Run the following to verify what went wrong:

```
for(i in 1:length(names(usaUnion))){
  print(length(usaUnion@polygons[[i]]@Polygons))
}
```

For each of these, you took only the first one.

I got a correct polygon join/plot with the following code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(plyr)

usa <- readOGR(dsn = "INSERT_YOUR_PATH", layer="light_shape")
# remove NAs
usa <- usa[!is.na(usa$segment_ID), ]
usaIDs <- usa$segment_ID

#get unique colors
set.seed(666)
unique_colors <- sample(grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y|white', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)], 15)

colors <- plyr::mapvalues(
  usaIDs, 
  from = as.numeric(sort(as.character(unique(usaIDs)))), #workaround to get correct color order
  to = unique_colors
)
plot(usa, col = colors, main = "Original Map")


usaUnion <- unionSpatialPolygons(usa, usaIDs)
plot(usaUnion, col = unique_colors, main = "Joined Polygons")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using `sf` to do this plot which highlights how the package's ability to work with `dplyr` and `summarise` in particular can make this operation extremely expressive and succinct. I `filter` out the missing IDs, `group_by` the ID, `summarise` (which does union by default), and easily plot with `geom_sf`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
# Substitute wherever you are reading the file from
light_shape <- read_sf(here::here("data", "light_shape.shp"))
light_shape %>%
  filter(!is.na(segment_ID)) %>% 
  group_by(segment_ID) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(segment_ID)))
```

[image]